# SQL Developer glitch/bug

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a very weird glitch in Oracle SQL Developer. When I try to select the text that is in a quote block (see example beneath) the text disappears. It's not gone though, it is just not visible anymore. It is impossible to select some text that is between these quotes... [image]

Is this a bug/glitch or what is wrong?

Comment: It may have to do with your color scheme.  Try changing back to default, and see if the behavior persists.

Comment: It happened before I changed my schema

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Definitely a SQL Developer bug. Did not make any recent changes. Can't think of what it could be. Bizzare. Very annoying to the point of wanting to use a different tool.